# MKL: calling ?gbtrf

Tags: c, matrix, factorization

I have to use MKL to solve a system of linear equation. This system of equations is used to solve the 2D poisson problem, so exactly 5 diagonals will be different from 0. The matrix A of the system Ax=b is square and its size is n*n. I've examined the documentation from Intel and I'm a bit puzzled about the calling sequence. The prototype is:

```
lapack_int LAPACKE_dgbtrf( int matrix_order, lapack_int m, lapack_int n, lapack_int kl, lapack_int ku, <datatype>* ab, lapack_int ldab, lapack_int* ipiv );
```

1)matrix_order. Afaik the order of a matrix is the maximum between the number of rows and columns. Shouldn't the library figure it out from the second and the third parameter?

2)m and n. Are these referring to the original matrix A or the representation in band storage?

3)band storage. Given the structure of the problem, I have exactly d diagonals above and d diagonals below the main diagonal, so, including the extra rows for the factorization, the memory area for band storage should have (n*n)*(3*d+1) elements. The elements are column-wise. Am I right?

4)leading dimension. This should be (3*d+1)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1) According to the MKL documentation (http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-C124D9D6-BCF5-471E-B750-0CF9CD1ACB02.htm), the order states if the matrices are row or column-major (LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR or LAPACK_COL_MAJOR).

2) Correct, they are the "m" and "n" from the original matrix.

3) The size would be n * (3 * d + 1), and their layout would depend on 1).

4) Correct if the matrix is row-major.